# How to show list of strings in QT at run time?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui, qmessagebox

I have a list of strings during run time.

Any one help me to display these strings in QWidget. When I right click that string I need to have a option **show index** that will show index of that string in QMessageBox.

If it is possible means give some technical guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: See the [menu example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/mainwindows-menus.html).

Comment: @thuga: IMO, that is a lot more than what the OP wants.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes, but it's still very helpful.

Comment: @thuga: my experience shows a lot of code just confuses the beginners.

Comment: Simplest way to get strings to GUI is to create QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit, and append strings to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so let us start with the design for your use case...

- I would recommend using a QListWidget for a list. Each string could be a separate item.
- You could show a popup for right click, but if it only has the show index action, it does not really make that much sense on its own. You could just show the messagebox with that index right away.

I would write something like this below:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_listWidget(new QListWidget(this))
{
    QStringList myStringList = QStringList() << "foo" << "bar" << "baz";
    m_listWidget->addItems(myStringList);

    // Set up your action with the popup for right click if needed
    // and connect to the "triggered" signal of the particular action

    connect(listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem * item)), SLOT(showMessageBox(QListWidgetItem * item)));

   ...

}

void MyClass::showMessageBox(QListWidgetItem * item)
{
    Q_UNUSED(item)
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.setText(m_listWidget->currentRow());
    messageBox.exec();
}
```

If you have more actions for the right click, you could use a popup dialog, yes, with several actions placed onto, but so far, that does not seem to be the use case in here.

Comment: You are genius. Thank you again. :D :D. Edit: I needed pop up menu for adding some other menus for further process. but it is okay . now i learned to add pop up menu. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3176618: you are welcome, but please show more effort in the future with your questions.

Comment: I am new to programming, so i will try to do so.